# Finding line and position of text in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get de line number and position (on that line) of a specific word in a text.

For example:

```
--
This is my first line.
This is my second line.
--
```

If I would check for 'second' I should get something back like: `2,12`

Anyone any suggestion?

Comment: SQL Server is not really suited for this type of operation.  You would be better off using a text editing tool like Notepad++ or maybe Microsoft Word.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I need to do this on thousands of records ;-)  UPDATE MyTable SET Coordiante=dbo.fMyFunction(Fieldname,Argument)

Comment: Then you are probably looking at writing a proc or a user defined function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the first occurrence per line, and assuming a LINE is delimited by char(13) and not punctuation.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeText varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'This is my first line.
This is my second line.')
,(2,'This another but has a second note
Which not related to the prior "second" note')

Declare @Search varchar(100)='second'

Select A.ID
      ,Position=concat(RetSeq,',',charindex(@Search,RetVal))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                      ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(SomeText,char(10),''),char(13),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B
 Where charindex(@Search,RetVal)>0
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Position
1   2,12
2   1,24
2   2,33
```

> **EDIT - Requested EDIT**

```
Select Top 1 with Ties
       A.ID
      ,Position=concat(RetSeq,',',charindex(@Search,RetVal))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                      ,RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(SomeText,char(10),''),char(13),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B
 Where charindex(@Search,RetVal)>0
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by RetSeq)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Position
1   2,12
2   1,24
```

Comment: Hi John! This is almost what I need. Two small details: if a line starts with spaces they are not counted and I need only the line+col for the first occurence. Can you help me out?

Comment: @RonaldKas I currently remove the leading spaces with ltrim(rtrim(...))).   Did you want to keep the leading spaces?    So if the text can be found in multple lines, you only want the first?

Comment: @RonaldKas See Requested EDIT

Comment: @RonaldKas Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that does not make use of a subquery ; it relies on ,[SQL Server string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), such as `CHARINDEX` and `REVERSE`.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( @match, t.value ) < CHARINDEX( CHAR(10), t.value ) 
        THEN CONCAT( '1,', CHARINDEX( @match, t.value ) )
    ELSE
        CONCAT(
            LEN(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value))) 
                - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value)), CHAR(10), '')) + 1,
            ',',
            CHARINDEX (CHAR(10), REVERSE(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value)))) - 1
        )
    END
from t;
```

The principle is to first find the position of the searched string (`@match`), and then compute the position of the previous carriage return (`CHAR(10)` - could be also `CHAR(13)` depending on your EOF settings), using `REVERSE`. With these two values at hand, we can compute the position of the match on the line, and the line number (for this, we compare the length of the substring until the match to its length without carriage returns). Special care has to be taken when the match is on the first line.

**db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e1218d273aa89ed0a46d3938081ba73)**

```
 Declare @match varchar(100) = 'second';

 with t as (SELECT 'This is my first line.
 This is my second line.
 This is my third line.' value)
 SELECT 
     CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( @match, t.value ) < CHARINDEX( CHAR(10), t.value ) 
         THEN CONCAT( '1,', CHARINDEX( @match, t.value ) )
     ELSE
         CONCAT(
             LEN(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value))) 
                 - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value)), CHAR(10), '')) + 1,
             ',',
             CHARINDEX (CHAR(10), REVERSE(LEFT(t.value, CHARINDEX(@match, t.value)))) - 1
         )
     END
 from t;
 GO
```

```
 | (No column name) |
 | :--------------- |
 | 2,12             |
```